# How to deal with traffic mirroring encapsulated by gre?

Tags: network-traffic

[image]

NSX can only provide gre-encapsulated traffic mirroring, but security analysis tools cannot process gre packets.

What tool or software can strip the gre packet header and send the processed traffic mirroring to the security analysis tool

It is preferably a virtual machine or linux software.

It is preferably a virtual machine or linux software.